# How to make A - 1 = Z in Python?

Tags: python

I'm working on a code in python, that en/decrypts text. I want the en/decrypted text to be limited to letters (A-Z and a-z). So  `ord("A") - 1` should equal  `ord("Z")`

Is there a way to do this, that isn't impossible? Because that makes as much sense as  `65 - 1 = 90`

my code rn:

```
text = input("Text: ")
shift = int(input("Shift: "))
text2 = ""
for letter in text:
    help = ord(letter) + int(shift)
    text2 = text2 + chr(help)     
print(text2)
```

finally got the solution that worked perfectly for me:

```
    for letter in text:
        if letter.islower():
            help = (ord(letter) - ord("a") + shift) % 26 + ord("a")
            text2 = text2 + chr(help)
        if letter.isupper():
            help = (ord(letter) - ord("A") + shift) % 26 + ord("A")
            text2 = text2 + chr(hilf)
```

I had to rewrite the java code of the linked question to python

Still thank you all for the quick responses

Comment: Share your code, so the answer can match your case

Comment: Do you have to use `ord()`?  If you have a plain string `letters = 'ABCDE...'`, then `letters[-1]` will be `Z`.

Comment: You should add condition, if char value is 64 then write 90 to it.

Comment: You could now think about accepting an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using `chr` and `ord` you can do it easily

```
def get(letter: str, delta: int):
    return chr((ord(letter) - 97 + delta) % 26 + 97)

print(get('a', 1))  # b
print(get('a', -1))  # z

print(get('a', 30))  # same as +4 : 'e'
print(get('a', -30))  # same as -4 : 'w

print(get('a', 1_000))  # 'm'
print(get('a', -1_000))  # 'o'
```

You can also use the alphabet manually

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as low_ltt

def get(letter: str, offset: int):
    return low_ltt[(low_ltt.index(letter) + offset) % len(low_ltt)]
```

Comment: Instead of `low_ltt[...]` and `low_ltt.index(...)` you could rather use `chr` and `ord`.